# Error join database to SQL availability group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Can anyone help me with the following problem?  I get the following error when I try to join a database to an availability group

> "Restoring the database resulted in an error.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.HadrTasks)
>
> ---------------------------------------------- ADDITIONAL INFORMATION
>
> Restore failed for Server '[computername]\SQL01'.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.6020.0+((SQL11_PCU_Main).151020-1526+)@EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Restore+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The operating system returned the
>   error '5(Access is denied.)' while attempting
>   'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation
>   on'M:\UserLogs\OperationsManager.ldf'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.6020.0+((SQL11_PCU_Main).151020-1526+)&LinkId=20476
>
> ---

Background

- 2 Instances of SQL Server on two servers (Server1\instance1, Server1\instance2, Server2\instance1, Server2\instance2)
- SCCM databases on instance 1; SCOM databases on instance 2
- Moved SCCM databases to another server
- Changed collation on instance 1 on each server to the one used by the SCOM databases; restarted each server after doing this
- Detached OperationsManager database from instance 2, copied to instance 1 drives and attached to instance 1
- Created SQL Availability group on instance 1 for OperationsManager database
- Getting error message listed above when trying to add OperationsManager database to availability group
- Have checked permissions on instance 1 folders on both servers, also on share folder used to synch AG; have granted SQL Server instance, SQL Server service accounts (domain user accounts) full access to instance 1 folders and synch folder
- Have also made sure that SPNs for instance 1 on both servers are present & correct

Comment: Have you tried manually preparing the DBs to join the AG, by taking a full backup, plus at least one t-log backup, and restoring it to the secondary with norecovery? Do you get any errors when you step through manually? https://goo.gl/Or6XMS

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't have permission to the folder `M:\UserLogs\`.

Try the below method, it may be help you.

1. **Grant full access** to SQL server service account for M:\UserLogs. (Which must be a domain account)
2. **Manually restore** the database.
3. While adding the db to AG choose **JOIN ONLY**.